# save_file() not giving 'already exists' messagebox

Tags: enthought, traitsui

I'm trying to use the save_file() from traitsui.file_dialog, and I'm having a problem...the really odd thing is that if I run my code in Visual Studio (using PTVS), it works just fine!

Here's the problem as I see it...
When I use the dialog created by save_file() to pick an already existing file, I get NotImplemented errors in the iPython window of the Canopy editor, and I think it indicates that I don't have a FileExistsHandler in my code (I'm still in the early phases of learning Python/Canopy/Traits, so I may be all wet here :)).  I never get a 'File Already Exists' popup either.

However, when I run the same code from inside Visual Studio using PTVS, I do get the 'File Already Exists' popup with the option to accept it or cancel.

Why does the PTVS version work, and (more importantly) how can I get my Canopy Editor version to work???

Thanks for any hand-holding anyone can supply :)

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Steve, one simple thing to try in the Canopy preferences dialog's Python tab would be changing the GUI backend from Qt to WX.

Updating:

A somewhat more attractive and performant solution would be to continue using Qt but to use the file dialogs from pyface (pyface.api.FileDialog (Qt-specific; for the API, see https://github.com/enthought/pyface/blob/master/pyface/i_file_dialog.py).

Comment: Thanks again @Jonathan...changing from  Qt to WX fixed the missing pop-up, but any vertical 'springs' in the View stopped working...so my 'dialogs' don't look quite as nicely laid out :(

Answer (score 0):

Further Update...
Here's a simple block of code that works fine when using WX as the Python backend, but it has problems running using Qt:

```
from traitsui.file_dialog import save_file, TextInfo

import os

def SaveFile ( filename ):
    """ Handles the user clicking the 'SaveAs...' button.
    """
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):                   # if the file doesn't exist, just put the path into the file_name so I start in the same directory
        (filename, dummyname) = os.path.split(filename)
    filename = save_file( extensions  = TextInfo(),
    file_name  = filename,
    title      = 'Save File As...',
    )
    return filename

newfile = SaveFile('C:\\temp\\already_there.txt')
```

If you run this using WX, you get the pop-up 'File already exists...' dialog with OK/Cancel buttons...running using Qt on the backend produces no pop-up, and NotImplemented errors in the iPython window :(  (If I type in a new, non-existing filename, the save_file works correctly)

I really like the look of Qt screens, and someone told me that WX is for Windows only (I'm not sure of that, I haven't checked)

Is there a way I can get the save_file() to work correctly and error-free under Qt?